# I cannot change a global boolean var in a constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, 3d, three.js

Im trying to use a global variable called `_mouseoverdistancebool` in my constructor to notice when the mouse is over an object 3D called `distance` in `threejs`. But the value never changes. 
This is the code that affects the variable:

```
  constructor(targetMesh, controls, camera, container) {
    super();

    this._mouseoverdistancebool = false;

    this.addEventListeners();
  }

  addEventListeners() {
    this._distance.addEventListener('mouseleave', this.mouseleavedistance);
    this._distance.addEventListener('mouseenter', this.mouseenterdistance);

    this._container.addEventListener('mousewheel', this.onMove);
    this._container.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', this.onMove);

  }

  mouseenterdistance(evt) {
    console.log("Mouse over the object!!!");
    this._mouseoverdistancebool = true;
  }

  mouseleavedistance(evt) {
    console.log("Mouse leaves the object....");
    this._mouseoverdistancebool = false;
  }

  onMove(evt) {
    console.log(this._mouseoverdistancebool);
  }
```

So I can see in the debug that the events work well but the boolean is always false. Something like this:

```
>Mouse over the object!!!
>false
>Mouse leaves the object....
>false
```

Im new to constructors in javascript ... What Im doing wrong?

Comment: You can look into this feature - [transform class properties](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties). Which would allow you to do `onMove = (evt)=>{...}` and you should get the correct this in the callback

Comment: Solved with the duplicate question. thanks!